# How to insert into a Linked List at the end

Tags: java

I am learning linked list here https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/linked-list-insertion/1#

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/?ref=lbp

Here I have to write 2 functions to add a node at the beginning/the end of a linked list.

LinkedList: 9->0->5->1->6->1->2->0->5->0

The output should be: 5 2 9 5 6

But my output is: 5 2 9

I think I am wrong in the function add a node at the end, but I could not find my mistake. Could you please let me know where I am wrong?

> Create a link list of size N according to the given input literals.
> Each integer input is accompanied by an indicator which can either be
> 0 or 1. If it is 0, insert the integer in the beginning of the link
> list. If it is 1, insert the integer at the end of the link list.
> Hint: When inserting at the end, make sure that you handle NULL
> explicitly.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input:
> LinkedList: 9->0->5->1->6->1->2->0->5->0
> Output: 5 2 9 5 6
> Explanation:
> Length of Link List = N = 5
> 9 0 indicated that 9 should be
> inserted in the beginning. Modified
> Link List = 9.
> 5 1 indicated that 5 should be
> inserted in the end. Modified Link
> List = 9,5.
> 6 1 indicated that 6 should be
> inserted in the end. Modified Link
> List = 9,5,6.
> 2 0 indicated that 2 should be
> inserted in the beginning. Modified
> Link List = 2,9,5,6.
> 5 0 indicated that 5 should be
> inserted in the beginning. Modified
> Link List = 5,2,9,5,6. 
> Final linked list = 5, 2, 9, 5, 6.
> ```

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution
{
    //Function to insert a node at the beginning of the linked list.
    Node insertAtBeginning(Node head, int x)
    {
        // code here
        Node current = new Node(x);
        current.next = head;
        head = current;
        return head;
    }
    //Function to insert a node at the end of the linked list.
    Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int x)
    {
        // code here
        Node current = head;
        while(current.next != null){
            current = current.next;
        }
        Node addthis = new Node(x);
        current = addthis;
        return head;
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides the issue in the answer, pay attention to the `Hint: When inserting at the end, make sure that you handle NULL explicitly.` (namely when `head` is `null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is an issue in your `insertAtEnd()` method. You correctly iterate through to the tail of your linked list, but your problem is here:

```java
current = addthis;
```

This will simply assign your new node to `current`, which is not what you want.

What you want is, to attach your new node to the `next` field of your last node like this:

```
current.next = addthis;
```

This way, you actually added your node to the previously last element of the list.

Full code:

```
Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int x) {
    Node current = head;
    while(current.next != null){
        current = current.next;
    }
    Node addthis = new Node(x);
    current.next = addthis;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask you one more question: after the while loop, current is null, so do you add the new node after the null?

Comment: `public void addAtTheEnd(int x) {
  Node newNode = new Node(x);
  Node current = head;
  Node prev = null;
  
  
  while(current != null) { // run current to the end
   prev = current;
   current = current.next;
  }//end while
  
  //now current = the end = null
  prev.next = newNode;
  return;
 }//done add the end`

Comment: "After the while loop, current is null", no? Why would it? `current.next` is null after the while loop?

Comment: @Osiris If you have another question, please create a new question and ask it there. The comments are not the best place to post code and ask a new question.

Comment: Oh I understood, I wrote it again like this while(current != null), that's why I was confused. Thank you Maloomeister

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    //Function to insert a node at the beginning of the linked list.
    Node insertAtBeginning(Node head, int x) {
        Node node = new Node(x);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            return head;
        }
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
        return head;
    }
    
    //Function to insert a node at the end of the linked list.
    Node insertAtEnd(Node head, int x) {
        Node node = new Node(x);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            return head;
        }
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = node;
        return head;
    }
}
```